# Success message doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

I have a little issue,
I'm working on a contact form,
My problem is that the ajax call doesn't show a success message, it sticks
on "sending"
the call is working because it goes to the PHP page and runs the function from there, so everything works fine expect the success message.
I will really glad for assistance, thanks!

this is the JavaScript page:

```
  var nameRegx = /^[' a-zא-ת]+(\s[' a-zא-ת]+)*$/i,
    emailRegx = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})$/,
    phoneRegx = /^(?:0(?!(5|7))(?:2|3|4|8|9))(?:-?\d){7}$|^(0(?=5|7)(?:-?
     \d){9})$/,
    td = 'p.text-danger',
    sa = '#submitAnimate',
    sb = '#submitBtn',
    nf = '#name',
    ef = '#email',
    pf = '#phone',
    mf = '#message';

 $(sa).hide();

 $('#contactForm').on('submit', function (event) {

  event.preventDefault();
 var isValid = true;
 $(td).text('');
 $(' input[type="text"], textarea').removeClass('error');
$(sb).attr('disabled', true);
  $(sa).show();

 var userData = {
name: $(nf).val().trim(),
email: $(ef).val().trim(),
phone: $(pf).val().trim(),
message: $(mf).val().trim()
 };

 if (userData.name.length < 2 || userData.name.length > 70 || 
 !nameRegx.test(userData.name)) {
isValid = false;
  setError(nf, 'name');
  }

  if (!emailRegx.test(userData.email)) {
  isValid = false;
  setError(ef, 'email');
  }

if (!phoneRegx.test(userData.phone)) {
isValid = false;
setError(pf, 'phone');
   }

 if (userData.message.length < 3) {
isValid = false;
setError(mf, 'message');
 }

  if (!isValid) {

$(sb).attr('disabled', false);
setTimeout(function(){ $(sa).hide(); }, 500);

 } else {

  $.ajax({
  url: "assets/contact_form/process-contact.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  data: userData,
  beforeSend: function () {
    $( sb ).val('Sending...');
  },
  success: function (response) {

    if (response == true) {

    successmessage = 'Data was succesfully captured';
            $("#gmsg").text(successmessage);//THIS MESSAGE DOESN'T APPEAR


    } else {

      $( sb ).val('Can not send, please try latter');

    }
  }
});

  }

});

$('input[type="text"], textarea').on('keyup', function () {
  $(this).next().text('');
});

  function setError(target, field) {
setTimeout(function () {
   $(target).val('').addClass('error');
  $(target).next().text('* Please enter your ' + field);
  }, 500);
   }
```

Comment: try using if (response)  instead of if (response == true)

Comment: Please stop posting the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

In `success : function(response)` the object response is not a Boolean. it is the returned response of the ajax call, it will be a string.
just remove the `if(response == true)` from your code.
then, it will work fine.